# Como colocar somente itens verdadeiros na segunda Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou tentando fazer uma Activity de favoritos, vou seguir o exemplo desse cara [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001715/8535610). Na segunda Activity que irei criar como eu faria pra colocar esses itens setados como verdadeiros em uma listview? e reproduzi-los normalmente eu teria que recriar todo o codigo de reprodução na segunda Activity? e depois como eu faria para remove-los. 
Isso é um esquema de favoritos se alguem souber um tutorial bom ja é uma grande ajuda, obrigado.

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ArrayList<memes> item;
    ArrayAdapter<memes> arrayAdapter;
    String[] Nomes = new String[]{"Compartilhar meme", "Favoritos"};
    List<memes> favoriteMemes= new ArrayList<memes>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        isStoragePermissionGranted();

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        item = new ArrayList<>();
        //itens
        item.add(new memes("Arnold Musica", R.raw.diffrentstrokes));
        item.add(new memes("Aham sei  ", R.raw.ahamsei));
        item.add(new memes("2 mil anos", R.raw.milanos));
        item.add(new memes("Acelera jesus", R.raw.acelera_jesus));


        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //play audio
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Olá, Marilene!");
                builder.setItems(MainActivity.this.Nomes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                sendWhatsAppAudio(position);
                                return;
                            case 1:

                                item.get(position).setmIsFavourite(true);
                                return;
                            default:
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

//Aqui esta a bagunça 
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.abreFavoritos:
                for(int i=0;i<lv.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
                    memes fMeme = (memes)lv.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                    //mIsFavourite em meu codigo fica vermelho
                    //o que eu devo colocar depois do item. para que funcione?
                    if (item.mIsFavourite()) {
                        favoriteMemes.add(fMeme);
                    }
                }
                intent = new Intent(this, Favoritos.class);

                intent.putExtra("favoritos", new Gson().toJson(favoriteMemes));
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
              default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

}
```

### Favoritos.class

```
   public class Favoritos extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<memes> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);

        String memesString = getIntent().getStringExtra("favoritos");
        memes[] fMemes = new Gson().fromJson(memesString,memes[].class);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fMemes);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

### memes.class  (Adapter)

```
public class memes{

    private String nome;
    private int resID;
    private Boolean mIsFavourite;

    public memes(String nome, int resID){

        this.nome = nome;
        this.resID = resID;
    }

    public Boolean getmIsFavourite() {
        return mIsFavourite;
    }

    public void setmIsFavourite(Boolean mIsFavouriteResource) {
        this.mIsFavourite = mIsFavouriteResource;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public int getResId(){
        return resID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nome;
    }

}
```

Parece que estou bem atras do objetivo, caso n tenha tempo indique tutoriais ou links do que preciso estudar para fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Tudo Bem Welyson.
Recomendo que use **RecyclerView's** em vez de ListView's.

Segue [aqui](https://medium.com/android-dev-br/listas-com-recyclerview-d3f41e0d653c'%3E%20aqui) um bom tutorial.
Quanto a passar os itens verdadeiros para a 2a activity, tanto usando RecyclerView quanto na ListView, você terá de acessar o Adapter e verificar os itens "verdadeiros" e passa-los para 2a activity via "putExtras":

Notei que seu código não está muito objetivo. Marcarei algumas correções afim de que você dê prosseguimento:

Esta parte do código não parece em linha com seu objetivo. Acredito que você tenha programado um botão ou menu para acessar sua 2a atividade, e se for isso, crie um OnClickListener e associe ao botão:

```
View.OnClickListener abreFavoritos = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i=0;i<lv.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
            memes fMeme = (memes)lv.getAdapter().getItem(i));
            if(item.isFavorito()) favoriteMemes.add(fMeme);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Favoritos.class);
        //Passe a List<memes> como parâmetro extra para a 2a Activity
        intent.putExtra("favoritos", new Gson().toJson(favoriteMemes));

        //Esta parte esta faltando
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Para recuperar a lista na 2a activity use:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Recupere a Array com os Favoritos
        String memesString =getIntent().getStringExtra("favoritos");
        memes[] fMemes=new Gson().fromJson(memesString,memes[].class);
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar e volto aqui, vlw msm estava procurando isso a tempos

Comment: Sua explicação parece ser ótima mas estou meio perdido, Atualizei a postagem com meu codigo, quando tiver um tempinho pode me ajudar ou indicar tutoriais para que eu possa preencher a falta de conhecimento? Obrigado

Comment: Notei que seu código não está muito objetivo. Marcarei algumas correções afim de que você dê prosseguimento:
Esta parto do código não parece em linha com seu objetivo. Acredito que você tenha programado um botão ou menu para acessar sua 2a atividade, e se for isso, crie um OnClickListener e associe ao botão:
View.OnClickListener abreFavoritos = new View.OnClickListener(){
}

Comment: ei maicon os itens não estão sendo exibidos na segunda activity atualizei o codigo de uma olhada
E tbm caso eu consiga arruma como eu faria na activity Favoritos remove-los

Comment: Remova o item de seu adapter e notifique a remoção.

Comment: Blz, mas e os itens que não estão sendo exibidos, poderia olhar meu codigo?

Comment: Qual IDE vc está usando, Eclipse ou Android Studio?
Mandarei um exemplo para vc analisar.

Comment: android studio
Obrigado

Comment: Me passe um endereço de e-mail para que eu lhe envie um modelo de projeto para vc ter como base.

Comment: welyson205@gmail.com